# Youtube video with ads if watched at YouTube, but no ads if watched in Learning Management System

Tags: youtube, ads

I've created YouTube videos with educational content. At YouTube they have ads. I've created as well a learning management system (LMS) where it provides a structure as well as monitoring/analytics features. It loads the same YouTube videos. Teachers and students subscribe to the LMS as such I don't want to show ads. How do I set my videos such that if it is consumed in YouTube there are ads, but if it is loaded at the LMS, there are no ads. Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596

Comment: @kirjosieppo Thank you for the input! Apologies for the delayed response...